# Installation of SQL Server 2012 does not contain Virtual Interface Adapter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have installed the entire Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2012 and have noticed that I do not have the Virtual Interface Adapter.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Virtual Interface Adapter has been deprecated and removed in SQL Server 2012.

[Choosing a Network Protocol - SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> The VIA protocol is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

[Configure Client Protocols - SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181035.aspx)

> Microsoft SQL Server supports client communication with the TCP/IP network protocol and the named pipes protocol. The shared memory protocol is also available if the client is connecting to an instance of the Database Engine on the same computer. There are three common methods of selecting the protocol.
>
> •Configure all client applications to use the same network protocol by setting the protocol order in SQL Server Configuration Manager.
>
> •Configure a single client application to use a different network protocol by creating an alias. For more information, see Create or Delete a Server Alias for Use by a Client (SQL Server Configuration Manager).
>
> •Some client applications, such as sqlcmd.exe, can specify the protocol as part of the connection string. For more information, see Connect to the Database Engine With sqlcmd.